# LinqDataSource: Filtering and binding to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linqdatasource

**the problem is not solved the way i wanted but i go ahead give the credit to : ŁukaszW.pl for his time and effort.**

i am using gridview control and a linqdatasource and its all working fine and i have added the functionlity of searchingBySubject and i added WhereParameters and than binding my gridview (see the code below) but somehow its not returning any rows and i see i have number of rows based on what i am searching.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
   this.LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue = this.txtSubject.Text;
   this.GridView1.DataBind();
 }

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
         DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"  
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."> 
        <Columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" ReadOnly="True"  
                SortExpression="UserID" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username"  
                SortExpression="Username" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  
                SortExpression="FirstName" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  
                SortExpression="LastName" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" /> 
        </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView> 

     <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"  
        ContextTypeName="MyDataContextDataContext" 
        onselecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting" > 
            <WhereParameters> 
               <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" />
            </WhereParameters> 
        </asp:LinqDataSource>



public List<Reporter> GetInquiries()
        {
            using (MyDataContextDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
            {
                var loadAll = (from spName in dc.spReporter()
                               select spName);

                List<Reporter> reporterList = new List<Reporter>();

                foreach (var item in loadAll)
                {
                    reporterList.Add(new Reporter(item.Id, item.InqDate, item.Subject));
                }                

                return reporterList;
            }
```

**ERROR:**

```
 The query results cannot be enumerated more than once
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the problem, I don't see any connection between your GetInquiries method and LinqDataSource. Thats first, second is that even if there will be connection it will not work if you are returning list, and not IQueriable object...

To better uderstand binding with LinqDataSource read [this Scott Gu's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx)

Also I want to show you that your GetInquiries method could be simplified to this form:

```
    public List<Reporter> GetInquiries()
    {
        using (MyDataContextDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
        {
            return (from spName in dc.spReporter()
                    select new Reporter(spName.Id, spName.InqDate, spName.Subject)).ToList()

        }
```

---- EDITED ----

Example of alternative solution:

```
    public List<Reporter> GetInquiries(string subject)
    {
        using (MyDataContextDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
        {
            return (from spName in dc.spReporter()
                    select new Reporter(spName.Id, spName.InqDate, spName.Subject
                    where spName.Subject == subject)).ToList()

        }  
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
       GridView1.DataSource = GetInquiries(txtSubject.Text);
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

---------- EDIT -------------

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   this.LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue = this.txtSubject.Text;
   this.GridView1.DataBind();
}

public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{ 
    ReporterRepository reporterRepo = new ReporterRepository();
    e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries();    
}

public IQueryable<Reporter> GetInquiries()
{
    return from spName in dc.spReporter()
           select new Reporter(spName.Id, spName.InqDate, spName.Subject);
}     

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."> 
        <Columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" ReadOnly="True"  
                SortExpression="UserID" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username"  
                SortExpression="Username" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  
                SortExpression="FirstName" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  
                SortExpression="LastName" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" /> 
        </Columns> 
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="MyDataContextDataContext" onselecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting"> 
        <WhereParameters> 
           <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" />
        </WhereParameters> 
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... what you mean returning IQueriable object, can you please show me few lines? or i was thinking should i add where clause in my GetInquiries() or it will take care automatically since i am adding where clause in the linqdatasource?

Comment: Right now I think, that there is no need to use LinqDataSource... Just use GetInquiries method to get list of Reporters and then assign it to your gridView as normal DataSource. Example above.

Comment: oops, sorry i have update (LinqDataSource_Selecting) the question

Comment: Haha.. now it make more sense.. try then return the GetInquiries which returns pure IQuerable (without ToList method) or if it won't work try my alternative solution :)

Comment: i have thought of using the alternative solution you presented before posting this question but later i thought it will be too much because i have like 7 items to filter like (by date, by subject, by status.....)

Comment: I like to use ObjectDataSource instead of LinqDataSource... It's quite similar to what's you're doing : I create a list of objects manually...

Comment: But ObjectDataSource won't dynamicly work with database. What about returning IQuerable<Reporter> as a result of GetInquiries? Any results?

Comment: @KukaszW: i have created IQueryable (i upate my question) but how will call that?

Comment: Just like you do it on the beginning, return it as e.Result.. I guess it should work then ;)

Comment: i update my question, please see and its throwing me some errors, may be i am not calling the way it should call.

Comment: Excuse me, but in which line did you get it?

Comment: sory man this is driving me crazy now... i have update my question, getting error on IQueryable<Reporter> GetInquiries()

Comment: I was just about to suggest it.. And what, now it works okay?

Comment: oh boy, new error now: "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once"

Comment: k so i fixed this by returning reporterRepo.GetInquiries().ToList(); and it run the app but when i search by txtSubject, no change at all shows the same amount of data...egggrrrrrr

Comment: I'm not sure if we doing it right :P Imo it's not prepared to be used this way. It will be better if you will use alternative solution I've presented at the begining...

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that you declare a [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb516252.aspx) like this in your page:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1"
                    runat="server"  
                    ContextTypeName="MyDataContext"
                    OnSelecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Subject"
                              ControlID="txtSubject"
                              PropertyName="Text"
                              Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Your [LinqDataSource.Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.selecting.aspx) event handler should roughly look like this:

```
public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
     var db = new MyDataContext())
     var subjectFilter = e.WhereParameters("Subject");
     var reporters = from spName in db.spReporter()
                     where spName.Subject.Contains(subjectFilter)
                     select new Reporter(spName.Id, spName.InqDate, spName.Subject);
     e.Result = reporters;
}
```

**Alternatively** you could add 'Subject' as an input parameter to the Stored Procedure and to the filtering in the database. In that case the event handler would look like this:

```
public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
     var db = new MyDataContext())
     var subjectFilter = e.WhereParameters("Subject");
     var reporters = from spName in db.spReporter(subjectFilter)
                     select new Reporter(spName.Id, spName.InqDate, spName.Subject);
     e.Result = reporters;
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [LinqDataSource - Working with Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb516252.aspx#working_with_stored_procedures)